# Prove that positive $x,y$ satisfy $\left(\frac{1}{1+x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{1+y}\right)^2\ge\frac{1}{1+xy}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, substitution, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> Prove that positive $x,y$ satisfy $$\left(\frac{1}{1+x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{1+y}\right)^2\ge\frac{1}{1+xy}$$

My teacher claims this lemma is often useful. How to prove it?

I've tried using $a^2+b^2\ge 2ab$ and $a^2+b^2\ge \frac{(a+b)^2}{2}$ and $\frac{a_1^2}{b_1}+\frac{a_2^2}{b_2}+\ldots+\frac{a_n^2}{b_n}\ge \frac{(a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_n)^2}{b_1+b_2+\ldots+b_n}$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not particularly elegant, but if you multiply everything out, you get
$$x^3y+xy^3+1\ge x^2y^2+2xy$$
And that's just $2$ simple AM-GM inequalities
$$x^3y+xy^3\ge2x^2y^2$$
$$x^2y^2+1\ge2xy$$

Comment: Not particularly elegant? You're too hard on yourself!

Comment: @DavidH I guess it's not too bad, but I'd like to see a better solution than "let's multiply by $(1+x)^2(1+y)^2(1+xy)$" (if there is :)

Comment: The region in the x-y plane in the second and fourth quadrants where  the inequality does not hold is bound by $x^3y+xy^3+1 =  x^2y^2+2xy$ and  $ xy = -1 $ ,  this is quite sharp.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x+y=2u$ and $xy=v^2$.

Hence, we need to prove that
$$\frac{2+2x+2y+x^2+y^2}{(1+x+y+xy)^2}\geq\frac{1}{1+xy}$$ or
$$(1+v^2)(2+4u+4u^2-2v^2)\geq(1+2u+v^2)^2$$ or
$$1+4u^2v^2-3v^4-2v^2\geq0$$ or
$$(1-v^2)^2+4v^2(u^2-v^2)\geq0,$$ 
which is true because $u^2\geq v^2$ it's just $(x-y)^2\geq0$.

Done!

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach: we can divide it into cases.

**Case 1:** $x,y \geq 1$ or $x,y \leq 1$

Using $a^2+b^2\ge 2ab$, which yields
$$
\left(\frac{1}{1+x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{1+y}\right)^2\ge\frac{2}{1+x+y+xy}
$$
We must then show that
$$
\frac{2}{1+x+y+xy}\geq \frac{1}{1 + xy} \iff\\
2 + 2xy \geq 1 + x + y + xy \iff\\
1 - x - y + xy \geq 0 \iff\\
(x-1)(y-1) \geq 0
$$

**Case 2:** Otherwise

Not sure what to do here yet.  Hopefully, this partial answer can be useful.